# Finding 0% code coverage

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I want to see which classes and triggers have 0%. But now that code coverage percentages are not shown in the list views of Classes or Triggers and the Developer Console Tests tab does not display classes or triggers with 0% I have to essentially try to figure out which classes or triggers aren't being displayed in the Developer Console in order to find the ones which are at 0%.

So is there a quicker way to find out which components have 0% code ?

Thank you.

Comment: Here is a post that might offer some further insight, http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/11/code-coverage-and-the-force-com-developer-console.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install eclipse or Mavens Mate then you can run all tests and see code coverage.

Have a look at http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation for the eclipse install instructions.

why oh why did SFDC feel the need to remove this function from the UI....

Answer (score 1):

We have a case open with salesforce for something related to code coverage (production code coverage dropped from 80% to 70% since winter 14). I was on a call with them and they were manually going to go through all the classes to see if there were classes with 0% code coverage. I asked him if there was an easier way and he said no.

So the official answer is: No. Unfortunately...

Comment: Somewhat related : I currently have a Case open with Salesforce in which I am unable to deploy because one of my triggers is showing 0% coverage during deployment, but 83% in the UI. Still waiting on a response. In the meantime, I can't deploy anything.